# How to parse html correctly with tag ol and strong

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to handle the deep ol, li and strong tag but facing some issue.

Here is what i had achieved

Example 1 (no problem)

```
<p>Good <strong>morning</strong></p>
```

Result : Good **morning**

Example 2

```
<ol><li>Good <strong>morning</strong></li></ol>
```

Result : 1. **morning**

As you can see the result 1 is working fine however the result 2 only keep the bold part when combined with ol tag. I'm not sure which part i did wrong.

Here is my Code

```
             function parseHtml(html, tagName) {
                var text = [],
                    obj = {},
                    css = [],
                    styles = {
                        strong: {bold: true},
                        em: {italics: true},
                        u: {decoration: 'underline'}
                    }
                ;
                angular.forEach(html, function (v) {

                    // init obj by merging into available styles
                    obj = styles[tagName] || {};
                    // recursive process                    
                        obj = angular.merge(parseHtml(v.children, v.tagName), obj);

                    }
                    // push to stack
                    this.push(obj);
                }, text);
            }

            return parseHtml(window.himalaya.parse(html));
```

The parameter of `html` contains the `<ol><li>Good <strong>morning</strong></li></ol>` and ready for parsing.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `parseHtml` function? The styles can easily be applied with css classes and if you want to sanitize, there are other inbuilt functions

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Basically i need parseHtml for json purpose. I used library called Himalaya.